# Cypress Child Custom Commands - Not enough arguments

Tags: typescript, cypress

I have `commands.ts` that looks like this:

```
declare namespace Cypress {
  interface Chainable<Subject> {
    foo: typeof foo;
  }
}

function foo(subject, s: string): Cypress.Chainable<JQuery> {
  console.log("bar");
  return cy.wrap(subject).type(s);
}

Cypress.Commands.add('foo', { prevSubject: 'element' }, foo);
```

This works exactly as intended, but when I call `cy.get('bar').foo('bar bar')`, VS Code gives me this warning:

```
Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.ts(2554)
commands.ts(38, 25): An argument for 's' was not provided.
```

I'm guessing I'm missing something in `tsconfig.json` to tell TypeScript that the first argument in child commands will implicitly be the previous subject.